# Implementing Either Monad in Typescript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, either

I've been experimenting with TypeScript lately, and I'm trying to implement some basic monads. I've already got a reasonably functioning Maybe (with the same methods of my Either below, at least), but Either is eluding me for type-related reasons I don't quite understand.

My typing strategy for higher kinded types is borrowed from this article: https://medium.com/@gcanti/higher-kinded-types-in-typescript-static-and-fantasy-land-d41c361d0dbe. I know there are libraries that already have all these monads and other FP goodies, but implementing them like this is my way of trying to learn TypeScript more deeply.

```
declare module './HKT' {
  interface TypeIDtoHKT2<E, A> {
    Either: Either<E, A>;
  }
}

export const TypeID = 'Either';
export type TypeID = typeof TypeID;

export class Left<E> {
  readonly _F!: TypeID;
  readonly _A!: E;
  readonly _tag: 'Left' = 'Left';
  constructor(readonly left: E) {}
  static of<E, A>(e: E): Either<E, A> {
    return new Left(e);
  }
  map<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B): Either<E, B> {
    return this;
  }
  chain<A, B>(f: (a: A) => Either<A, B>): Either<E, B> {
    return this;
  }
  ap<A, B>(f: Either<A, (a: A) => B>): Either<E, B> {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Right<A> {
  readonly _F!: TypeID;
  readonly _A!: A;
  readonly _tag: 'Right' = 'Right';
  constructor(readonly right: A) {}
  static of<A, E>(a: A): Either<E, A> {
    return new Right(a);
  }
  map<E, B>(f: (a: A) => B): Either<E, B> {
    return Right.of(f(this.right));
  }
  chain<E, B>(f: (a: A) => Either<E, B>): Either<E, B> {
    return f(this.right);
  }
  ap<E, B>(f: Either<E, (a: A) => B>): Either<E, B> {
    if (f instanceof Left) return f;
    return this.map(f.right);
  }
}

export type Either<E, A> = Left<E> | Right<A>;

export const left = <E, A>(e: E): Either<E, A> => {
  return new Left(e);
};

export const right = <E, A>(a: A): Either<E, A> => {
  return new Right(a);
};
```

When I try to run a test assertion, such as `right(4).map(isEven) === true`, I get the following error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<E, B>(f: (a: number) => B) => Either<E, B>) | (<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => Either<unknown, B>)' has no compatible call signatures.`

I don't understand why the `E` type is `unknown` here or how I can make it known...or if that's even the right thing to be trying to do. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I tried all your example here https://repl.it/repls/ExtralargeFixedAssembly and works just fine. What version of Node and TS are you using?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero I'm using Node 12.6.0 and TS 3.5.3. But more importantly, if I add the `right(4).map(isEven)` it does not compile. See https://repl.it/repls/BaggySuperficialGlueware

Comment: When I use Javascript syntax in a way it is not intended for it is called a hack. Using TS interfaces for faking higher kinded types is just that kind of misuse and I guess what you're experiencing are the consequences of relying on a hack.

Comment: @bob that's a fair point. I agree it is a clumsy solution. Is your suggestion that TS just isn't a good language choice here, and I should just go back to using algebraic structures in JS? Or do you have a better TS implementation suggestion for such structures?

Comment: If you really want to apply typed purely functional idioms than you should use purescript, because it is industry proofed. It's a hard step, though, especially when you come from imperative Javascript. Typescript is probably a good choice if you stick with OOP-style.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
export const left = <E, A>(e: E): Either<E, A> => {
  return new Left(e);
};

export const right = <E, A>(a: A): Either<E, A> => {
  return new Right(a);
};
```

this will work just fince:

```
console.log(isEven(3))
console.log((new Right(4)).map(isEven))
```

this will work also:

```
console.log(right(3))
```

but when you try to do:

```
right(3).map(isEven)
```

the compiler goes crazy and can't bind the type correctly. I think it is a limitation of the language. just don't use that constans and use directly the constructor.